Angular 14 - D3 Package running an unintended animation on a node which was not clicked
I'm new to D3 package. I'm currently working on a network topology visualization a using D3 on Angular 14 project. The network topology structure is described below:

L0: 0001

L1: 0002
L1: 0003

L2: 0009


L1: 0004

L2: 0005

L3: 0006


L2: 0007

L3: 0008







The visualized of full collapsed topology is attached below:

Based on my current code, sometimes running an animation on a node that was not clicked. Here is the example:

The data need to be rendered using D3 package are as follows:
const treeData: TreeItem[] = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [],
        data: {
          mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:2a",
          ip: "fd00:2736:6870::2",
          parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::1",
          rssi: -26,
          etx: 128,
          shortIp: "0002",
        },
      },
      {
        children: [
          {
            children: [],
            data: {
              mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:9a",
              ip: "fd00:2736:6870::9",
              parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::3",
              rssi: -32,
              etx: 134,
              shortIp: "0009",
            },
          },
        ],
        data: {
          mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:3a",
          ip: "fd00:2736:6870::3",
          parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::1",
          rssi: -27,
          etx: 129,
          shortIp: "0003",
        },
      },
      {
        children: [
          {
            children: [
              {
                children: [],
                data: {
                  mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:6a",
                  ip: "fd00:2736:6870::6",
                  parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::5",
                  rssi: -30,
                  etx: 132,
                  shortIp: "0006",
                },
              },
            ],
            data: {
              mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:5a",
              ip: "fd00:2736:6870::5",
              parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::4",
              rssi: -29,
              etx: 131,
              shortIp: "0005",
            },
          },
          {
            children: [
              {
                children: [],
                data: {
                  mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:8a",
                  ip: "fd00:2736:6870::8",
                  parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::7",
                  rssi: -32,
                  etx: 134,
                  shortIp: "0008",
                },
              },
            ],
            data: {
              mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:7a",
              ip: "fd00:2736:6870::7",
              parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::4",
              rssi: -31,
              etx: 133,
              shortIp: "0007",
            },
          },
        ],
        data: {
          mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:38:4a",
          ip: "fd00:2736:6870::4",
          parentIp: "fd00:2736:6870::1",
          rssi: -28,
          etx: 130,
          shortIp: "0004",
        },
      },
    ],
    data: {
      mac: "30:9f:fb:00:00:00:39:1a",
      ip: "fd00:2736:6870::1",
      parentIp: null,
      rssi: null,
      etx: null,
      shortIp: "0001",
    },
  },
];

The data is rendered using the following function:
renderTreeChart(treeData: TreeItem[]) {
  this.root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], (d: any) => d.children);

  this.element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

  const width =
    (this.root.height * 20 + this.treeStyle.barWidth + this.treeStyle.margin * 2) *
    this.treeStyle.ratioX;

  const height =
    (this.nodeSum * this.treeStyle.barHeight + this.treeStyle.margin * 2) * this.treeStyle.ratioY;

  this.svg = d3
    .select(this.element)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${this.treeStyle.margin},${this.treeStyle.margin})`);

  this.root.x0 = 0;
  this.root.y0 = 0;
  this.diagonal = d3
    .linkHorizontal()
    .x((d: any) => d.y)
    .y((d: any) => d.x + this.treeStyle.barHeight / 2);
  this.initTree(this.root);
  this.childrenCollapse(this.root);
  this.chartUpdate(this.root);
}

When one of the node has child and clicked, it will collapsed/hide it's child. The following methods are used to collapse/hide node's child:
nodeClick(node) {
  if (!node.children && !node._children) return;
  this.childrenUpdate(node);
  setTimeout(() => this.chartUpdate(node), 10);
}

childrenUpdate(node) {
  node.state = !node.state;
  if (node.children) {
    node._children = node.children;
    node.children = null;
  } else {
    node.children = node._children;
    node._children = null;
  }
}

chartUpdate(source: TreeItem) {
  // Compute the flattened node list.
  const nodes = this.root.descendants();
  const height =
    (nodes.length * this.treeStyle.barHeight + this.treeStyle.margin * 2) * this.treeStyle.ratioY;

  d3.select('svg').transition().duration(this.treeStyle.duration).attr('height', height);
  d3.select(self.frameElement)
    .transition()
    .duration(this.treeStyle.duration)
    .style('height', `${height}px`);

  let nodeIndex = -1;
  this.root.eachBefore((n) => {
    n.x = ++nodeIndex * this.treeStyle.barHeight * this.treeStyle.ratioY;
    n.y = n.depth * 20 * this.treeStyle.ratioX;
  });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  const node = this.svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes, (d: any) => {
    return d.id;
  });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  const nodeEnter = node
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${source.y0}, ${source.x0})`)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .on('click', (_, d: any) => this.nodeClick(d));

  // Add rectangle for the nodes
  nodeEnter
    .append('rect')
    .attr('y', -this.treeStyle.barHeight / 2)
    .attr('height', this.treeStyle.barHeight)
    .attr('width', this.treeStyle.barWidth)
    .attr('rx', 8)
    .style('stroke', (d: any) =>
      d._children ? '#fd7e50' : d.children ? '#ffcfbd' : 'transparent'
    )
    .style('fill', (d: any) => this.treeStyle.colors[d.depth % this.treeStyle.colors.length]);

  // Add text for the nodes
  nodeEnter
    .append('text')
    .attr('dy', 5)
    .attr('dx', 18)
    .style('fill', '#000')
    .style('font', '14px times')
    .text((d: any) => `IP: [${d.data.data.shortIp}]  MAC: [${d.data.data.mac}]`);

  // UPDATE
  const nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate
    .transition()
    .duration(this.treeStyle.duration)
    .attr('transform', (d: any) => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)
    .style('opacity', 1);

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate
    .select('rect')
    .style('stroke', (d: any) =>
      d._children ? '#fd7e50' : d.children ? '#ffcfbd' : 'transparent'
    )
    .style('fill', (d: any) => this.treeStyle.colors[d.depth % this.treeStyle.colors.length]);

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  const nodeExit = node.exit().style('opacity', 0).remove();

  // On exit reduce the node rectangle size to 0
  nodeExit.select('rect').attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text').style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  const link = this.svg.selectAll('.link').data(this.root.links(), (d: any) => {
    return d.id;
  });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  const linkEnter = link
    .enter()
    .insert('path', 'g')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', '#ccc')
    .style('stroke-width', '2px')
    .attr('d', (d) => {
      const o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 + 20 };
      return this.diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
    });

  // UPDATE
  const linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition().duration(this.treeStyle.duration).attr('d', this.diagonal);

  // Remove any exiting links
  const linkExit = link.exit();
  linkExit.remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  this.root.each((d) => {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

If I set the animation duration into 0 ms, the unintended animation will not show and seem's no re-rendering effect to the user. What I expect is how run the animation only on the clicked node without affecting other nodes?
My Reference:

Angular D3 tree does not collapse back into its parent
Collapsible Tree

